# can I fire a notification when popover had disappeared (iPad)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, notifications, uipopovercontroller

I need to know by notification or whatever when the user press outside the popover frame.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover: in the documentation.  It might suit your needs.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you implement `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` protocol?

Suppose you have a controller called `MyController` that displays the popover.
In MyController.h says that it implements `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` like the following;

```
@interface DocumentViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

Now, in .m somewhere you could display the popover and set its delegate to `self` (it means that `MyController` will be the delegate for the popover).

```
UIPopoverController* pop = // init the popover here
pop.delegate = self;
```

At this point, you could implement the methods that are listed in that protocol (you must implement the required one, in general). In your case you could implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    // here I'm closing the popover...
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{    
    // here I closed the popover...
}
```

For further info see [UIPopoverControllerDelegate class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Obviously in the first case, you need to return a `BOOL` value!!